# Spring security 3.1 authentication LDAP with md5

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

When we try to authenticate using the spring authentication manager, its says "bad credentials":

```
Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("john", "johnldap");
result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
```

Here the SecurityApplicationContext.xml file:

```
  <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapLocal"
            user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com">         
        </ldap-authentication-provider> 
    </authentication-manager>
    <ldap-server url="ldap://127.0.0.1:389/dc=example,dc=com" manager-dn="admin" manager-password="xxxxxxxx" id="ldapLocal"  />
```

However using "ldapsearch" we can connect successfully:

```
ldapsearch -D "uid=john,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" -w johnldap  -L "objectClass=*"
```

At first time we thought the issue was that we've to tell spring to do a md5 of the password before call LDAP. So we add it to the applicationSecurtyContext.xml:

```
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"  class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapLocal"
            user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com">  
         <password-compare>
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"> </password-encoder>
        </password-compare>
        </ldap-authentication-provider> 
    </authentication-manager>
    <ldap-server url="ldap://127.0.0.1:389/dc=example,dc=com" manager-dn="admin" manager-password="xxxxxxxx" id="ldapLocal"  />
```

But when we add the  tag it says:

```
LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the `user-dn-pattern` should not contain the root dn, as it will be automatically appended. So try using:

```
user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=People">
```

And I don't think you need the `password-encoder` if you only want to do a simple bind authentication.

Comment: I've tried it and it says: ***LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]***, even I've attempted to pass the password in md5 directly: new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("john", "905514952b7a4248db5147f501eaa48d");. Do you know any way to tell spring to get out some extra debug information to watch the real query that it's sending to the LDAP server?

Comment: Try enabling trace/debug level logging for `org.springframework.ldap`.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to connect with spring security, looking at stackoverflow I also thought that it may be problem with encoding, because passwords are in md5, though **I had to add mentioned above root dn separately**, password gets encoded by ldap server. Below is my working version:

```
<ldap-server url="ldap://dsa.company.com:389/" manager-dn="cn=manager,dc=company,dc=com"
    manager-password="pass"></ldap-server>
<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        user-dn-pattern="cn={0},ou=people,dc=company,dc=com"
        group-search-base="ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com" />
</authentication-manager>
```